# Cannot resolve 'findViewById' method in Fragment RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android studio, I was trying to create RecyclerView on Fragment. I was following a tutorial but I still get message ' Cannot resolve 'findViewById'

I've tried doing:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

But ended up receiving error:

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Articles extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        NewsList[] myListData = new NewsList[] {
                new NewsList("Article 1", "Some Author"),
                new NewsList("Article2", "Some Author"),
                new NewsList("Article3", "Some Author"),

        };
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(myListData);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
    }


}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these variables:

```
View root;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Change your onCreateView to this:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    return root;
}
```

and lastly - make sure that your recyclerview within your XML file has the following:

```
 android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
```

Comment: I don't really why the mark "+" was dropped in my XML code but finally thanks because I didn't know how to fix this. so that is interesting that one "+" confused of me for 1 min

Answer (score 2):

Your view is not yet inflated which is the reason it cannot be found. Move your code from `onCreate` to `onViewCreated` fragment lifecycle.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // your view is discoverable here
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    }
```

Comment: I did what you've told me and I moved my array in ```onViewCreated``` because it couldn't find ```myListData``` and I got ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference `

Answer (score 0):

For your example, your List (myListDatae) must be inside the NewsAdapter class as a field variable.